# JOOQ localDateTimeDiff with java.time.Duration's

Tags: java, jooq

I have a table with a created-timestamp (`timestamp`) and a time-to-live (`interval`).

```sql
CREATE TABLE my_object (
   id uuid NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
   created timestamp NOT NULL,
   time_to_live interval NOT NULL
);
```

Now I want to find all objects, where their TTL is over. I tried something like this:

```java
public class MyObjectRepository {

  public Stream<MyObjectDto> fetchExpired() {
    return context
        .selectFrom(MY_OBJECT)
        .where(localDateTimeDiff(currentLocalDateTime(), MY_OBJECT.CREATED)
            .greaterThan(MY_OBJECT.TIME_TO_LIVE))
            // ^- compile-error, no overload accepts TableField<MyObjectRecord, Duration>
        .forUpdate()
        .skipLocked()
        .fetchStreamInto(MyObjectDto.class);
  }
}
```

Perhaps the big-problem over here is, that I have the TTL forced typed into `java.time.Duration`. But for clean APIs, I can't change the type to `DayToSecond`.

```xml
<!-- others -->
<forcedType>
   <userType>java.time.Duration</userType>
   <converter>org.jooq.Converter.ofNullable(
      org.jooq.types.YearToSecond.class, Duration.class,
      yearToSecond -> yearToSecond.toDuration(), duration -> org.jooq.types.YearToSecond.valueOf(duration)
       )
   </converter>
   <includeTypes>INTERVAL</includeTypes>
</forcedType>
<!-- others -->
```

How can I do this in JOOQ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution going a little bit in the direction of [Michael Gantman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5802417/michael-gantman)s answer, but I don't get it to work.

So ... I changed the SQL-table a little bit. The new schema looks like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE my_object (
   id uuid NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
   created timestamp NOT NULL,
   valid_until timestamp NOT NULL
);
```

With the new schema, it was very easy to get JOOQ working. The code is simplified to this:

```java
public Stream<MyObjectDto> fetchExpired() {
  return context
      .selectFrom(MY_OBJECT)
      .where(MY_OBJECT.VALID_UNTIL.lessThan(ZonedDateTime.now()))
      .fetchStreamInto(MyObjectDto.class);
}
```

There are some other advantages in the new schema:

- More performant, because the eol-time must not be recalculated for each run
- More performant², because `valid_until` can be indexed
- Not breaking the API, because the TTL as `Duration` can be calculated (`valid_until - created`) if needed

Comment: This doesn't actually answer your question, where the premise was that you have an existing schema. You never mentioned that the schema can be changed.

Comment: I've also never forbid that. It is true that the answer wasn't directly addressed to problem but it solves the problem. My API is still unchanged (`valid_until = created + ttl`) and the migration is very easy. But feel free to write a new answer - bounty is still open.

Answer (score 2):

Use Duration class method `from()` with your TTL to create Duration instance with your TTL interval and than use Duration method `addTo()` with creation time to get moment when your TTL expires. Compare that moment to current time and if current time is after your expiration time than your record is expired. See Duration Javadoc [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html)